# How to display all columns on X axis on Barplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, bar-chart

I am trying to create a simple barplot showing years (2008-2022) on the x axis, and number of tweets on y axis.

However, R is automatically "skipping" certain years. Is there a way to have each year present on the x-axis under it's corresponding bar? I tried playing with "theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 0, size = 10))", but nothing changed.

Here is my code:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=created_at))+
  geom_bar(fill="steelblue")+
  theme_minimal() +
  labs(title="Number of Tweets per year", x="Year", y="Counts")
```

[image]

Comment: Something like `+ scale_x_continuous(breaks = 2008:2022)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's two ways you could achieve that:

- option 1: add `+ scale_x_continuous(breaks = 2008:2022)` as mentioned by @Axeman
- option 2: change "created_at" to factor, which can be done directly within `ggplot()`.

Some sample data

```
set.seed(1)
n = sample(10:140, 15)
data <- tibble("created_at" = rep(2008:2022, n))
```

Option 1

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = created_at)) +
  geom_bar(fill = "steelblue") +
  theme_minimal() +
  labs(title = "Number of Tweets per year", x = "Year", y = "Counts") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 2008:2022)
```

Option 2

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = factor(created_at))) +
  geom_bar(fill = "steelblue") +
  theme_minimal() +
  labs(title = "Number of Tweets per year", x = "Year", y = "Counts")
```

[image]